# MVC 3 Implement SessionStateStoreProviderBase to store data in cookies

Tags: asp.net, .net, session, cookies

I were trying to write my own custom SessionStateStoreProviderBase class and store data in cookies. 
But I have a problem, I don't know where I should add cookie with new values - into Response or into Request?
Could someone help me with this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cookies are stored on the client side.

If your cookies are new, then these are things that need to be sent back with the `Response`, as that's the only way to send cookies back to the client.

The cookies that come with the `Request` are being sent to you because that's what's *already* stored on the client and they're sending back that which you've already sent to them.

Since the cookies are *new*, the only way to set new cookies on the client is to send them back with a `Response`.

If you're implementing your own [`SessionStateStoreProviderBase`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.sessionstate.sessionstatestoreproviderbase.aspx) that uses cookies, then I'd suggest starting with the [`CreateNewStoreData` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.sessionstate.sessionstatestoreproviderbase.createnewstoredata.aspx).

You have to override this method when a new request comes in.  You get a reference to the [`HttpContext`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcontext.aspx) for the request, from which you can access the cookies.

The cookie would contain some key that would allow you to pull session state from whatever store you're using to store the session state (whether it be a database, files, etc).

Comment: Yes, I understand that, but SessionStateStoreProviderBase has a lot of overriden methods, and I don't know were I should use Response or Request. Do you know about it?

Comment: @user1934627 Updated my answer, the last three paragraphs show you where to start.